# Swift Members / Methods Accessibility Modifiers

Tags: swift

I have a very simple Swift question for which there is probably an obvious answer, but I can't seem to find it.

How are methods and variables within a class declared as:

- Private?
- Protected (i.e. accessible to children)?
- Internal (i.e. accessible to classes within the same package / namespace)?

Thanks in advance.